# Why Scheduled UNUserNotification never fire?

Tags: ios10

I have a function for schedule a UNUserNotification, I put it into a sample xcode project then it's work - the notification are shown.
But, when I bring it to real project (company's project) then UNUserNotification never show.
here are my code

```
UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
// create a category

UNNotificationCategory *inviteCategory = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:@"kNotificationCategoryToDoIdentifier"
                                                                                actions:@[]
                                                                      intentIdentifiers:@[]
                                                                                options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction];
NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:inviteCategory];

// registration
[center setNotificationCategories:categories];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *fireDateomponents = [gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond)
                                                   fromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSDateComponents * dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
dateComponents.calendar = gregorian;
dateComponents.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
dateComponents.year = fireDateomponents.year;
dateComponents.month = fireDateomponents.month;
dateComponents.day = fireDateomponents.day;
dateComponents.hour = fireDateomponents.hour;
dateComponents.minute = fireDateomponents.minute;
dateComponents.second = fireDateomponents.second + 10;


//Setup notification Triger
UNCalendarNotificationTrigger * trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:dateComponents
                                                                                                   repeats:NO];

UNMutableNotificationContent * content = [UNMutableNotificationContent new];
content.title = @"params.title";
content.body = @"params.body";
content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
content.badge = @(10);
content.categoryIdentifier = @"kNotificationCategoryToDoIdentifier";

//Crreate Notification Request
UNNotificationRequest * request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"requestId"
                                                                       content:content trigger:trigger];

//Schedule Notification
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * theError){
    NSLog(@"Scheduled : %@", [dateComponents date]);
    NSLog(@"WScheduled");
}];
```

Please help me !
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should check your `trigger.nextDate`. I guess your  `trigger.nextDate` is the time which you set trigger, but when the request is added into center, the nowtime is later than `trigger.nextDate`. So `UNUserNotification` never shows.
Have a try at

```
[[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * theError){
    NSLog(@"Scheduled : %@", [dateComponents date]);
    NSLog(@"Scheduled1 : %@", [trigger nextDate]);
    NSLog(@"Scheduled2 : %@", [NSDate date]);
    NSLog(@"WScheduled");
}];
```